# Trying to match some data across two sheets

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

I get

> "Type Mismatch" error

I have the following code that loops through two sheets, matching data and fills out column `"C"` and `"D"` accordingly. The code works perfectly up until I put in the `"And"` statements, at which point I get a `"Type mismatch"` error, and the debugging highlights that line too. I cannot figure out what is wrong, any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub ind_access_report()
Dim lastrow As Variant
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim x As Variant
Dim iName As String

    Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

iName = sh2.Range("A2").Value
lastrow = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To lastrow

    If sh1.Range("C" & x).Value = iName _
  Then sh2.Range("C" & x + 3).Value = sh1.Range("A" & x).Value _
   And sh2.Range("D" & x + 3) = "OWNER"

    If sh1.Range("D" & x).Value = iName _
  Then sh2.Range("C" & x + 3).Value = sh1.Range("A" & x).Value _
   And sh2.Range("D" & x + 3) = "BACKUP"

    If sh1.Range("E" & x).Value = iName _
  Then sh2.Range("C" & x + 3).Value = sh1.Range("A" & x).Value _
   And sh2.Range("D" & x + 3) = "BACKUP"


Next x
```

Comment: I'm sure there must be something on Google about this. The statements after `Then` must be on separate lines and without the `And`.

Comment: I used `If... Then... And` statements in a single line before in other macros with no issue whatsoever. It's not really a googleable issue.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I misread your code. Do you have any error values?

Comment: `And` is used as part of the `If`, not as part of the `Then`

Comment: my error value is `Type Mismatch`, don't have anything else to go by unfortunately. I don't understand why `And` is a part of `If` and not `Then` if it comes after `Then`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to rethink your line break strategy. It is the main reason of why it is failing. If you have a line break after `Then`, you will need an `End If`.
Try this:

```
Sub ind_access_report()
    Dim lastrow As Variant
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim iName As String

    Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    iName = sh2.Range("A2").Value
    lastrow = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To lastrow

        If sh1.Range("C" & x).Value = iName Then
            sh2.Range("C" & x + 3).Value = sh1.Range("A" & x).Value
            sh2.Range("D" & x + 3) = "OWNER"
        End If

        If sh1.Range("D" & x).Value = iName Then
            sh2.Range("C" & x + 3).Value = sh1.Range("A" & x).Value
            sh2.Range("D" & x + 3) = "BACKUP"
        End If

        If sh1.Range("E" & x).Value = iName Then
            sh2.Range("C" & x + 3).Value = sh1.Range("A" & x).Value
            sh2.Range("D" & x + 3) = "BACKUP"
        End If

    Next x
End If
```

Comment: Yep this one worked. I didn't need to put `End If` after `Next x` though, thank you so much. Didn't know line breaks can cause an issue, I thought it is only meant to make the code look tidier.

Comment: VBA is an old language. Line breaks are handled different here than in more modern langugages.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `And` correctly. You are probably trying to do multiple things in your `If` statement. Using `And` is not how you do it. Instead, use multiple lines and `End If` like this:

```
If sh1.Range("C" & x).Value = iName Then 
    sh2.Range("C" & x + 3).Value = sh1.Range("A" & x).Value
    sh2.Range("D" & x + 3) = "OWNER"
End If
```

Comment: I tried foregoing the `And` before, and I just get `End if without Block if ` error.

Comment: Then  you need to look more carefully at the structure of your `If` statements.